# Route didn't find controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code in webApi Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ForgotPassword")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return BadRequest("Either user does not exist or you have not confirmed your email.");
            }

            try
            {
                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                string callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default",
                    new { controller = "User/ManageAccount/reset-password", userId = user.Id, code = code }); //From UserController
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }

        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Here is UserController code:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult ManageAccount(string id)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            string page = "~/html/" + id + ".html";
            return new FilePathResult(page, "text/html");
        }
        return new FilePathResult("~/html/login.html", "text/html");
    }
}
```

The generated link is like this:
"http://localhost:7524/User/ManageAccount/reset-password?userId=4&code=ibrDwvzMjDerBPjRYFcKnATi6GpgIEGC1ytT6c%2Flsk4BF9ykxZWx8McBvxxBf%2F82csUGaCxpvgqY2eWUvirAxGJqP4I%2B9YHrVRpWmJN2u74xUP%2B%2BqAkfRf6d5gTz9kXVdWJQga2R1dpTy7tQC3OUWQ%3D%3D"

When I click it become like this:
https://localhost/User/ManageAccount/reset-password?userId=4&code=ibrDwvzMjDerBPjRYFcKnATi6GpgIEGC1ytT6c%2Flsk4BF9ykxZWx8McBvxxBf%2F82csUGaCxpvgqY2eWUvirAxGJqP4I%2B9YHrVRpWmJN2u74xUP%2B%2BqAkfRf6d5gTz9kXVdWJQga2R1dpTy7tQC3OUWQ%3D%3D

It seems that route didn't see UserController !!

Here is the route:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Here is the route of WebApi:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I want to ask you more about the process of clicking on the generated link from WebAPI. And when you access the second url, what is the result displayed from the browser? Error page from Asp WebServer or browser error page?

I guess the error you want to mention is caused by the fact that you ignored the server port in the url, which makes the browser unable to find your site. Note that debugging on IIS Express will give you a random webserver port, if you want this port to be fixed, as the default value of http is 80, deploy it with IIS.

To make it easier to understand, keep `http://localhost:7524/` instead of changing to `http://localhost/`. I think it will working right!!